# 'malloc(): corrupted top size' After allocating more than 200K int

Tags: c, sorting, malloc, openmp, buffer-overflow

I got assignment to do Bucket Sort with openMP, and I decided to do Quick Sort on each bucket. The requirement wants me to test by keep increasing the amount of integers and change the number of thread until reaching 1 million integers with 16 threads.

Here's my code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

}

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high) {

    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low - 1;

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {

        if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }

    }

    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);

    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) {

    if (low < high) {
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Check arguments
    if (argc > 3 || argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid arguments. This program require 2 arguments.\nUsage: ./bucketSort <thread number> <amount of random number>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Random seed");

    //Initialize random seed
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    int threadNum = atoi(argv[1]);
    int randomTime = atoi(argv[2]);

    int* numArr = (int*)malloc(randomTime * sizeof(int));

    if(numArr == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to allocate memory.");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nStart random");

    //Since RAND_MAX is limited to 0x7FFF (32,767), so we need to get creative to random beyond RAND_MAX
    for (int i = 0; i < randomTime; i++) {

        int rand1 = rand();
        int rand2 = rand();
        int rand3 = rand();

        int combinedRandom = ((rand1 % 100) * 1000) + ((rand2 % 100) * 10) + (rand3 % 10);

        numArr[i] = combinedRandom;

    }

    printf("\nFinished Random");

    double timeSpent = 0;

    int rangePerBucket = ceil(99999 / threadNum);

    int* outputArr = (int*)malloc(randomTime * sizeof(int));

    int* groupMemberCount = (int*)malloc(threadNum * sizeof(int));

    if(outputArr == NULL || groupMemberCount == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to allocate memory.");
        return 1;
    }

    clock_t begin = clock();

    printf("\nStart parallel section.");

    #pragma omp parallel shared(numArr, outputArr, groupMemberCount) num_threads(threadNum)
    {

        int myID = omp_get_thread_num();
        int totalThread = omp_get_num_threads();

        int beginRange = myID * rangePerBucket;
        int endRange = (myID + 1) * rangePerBucket - 1;

        int* temp = (int*)omp_alloc(rangePerBucket * sizeof(int), omp_large_cap_mem_alloc);

        if( temp == NULL ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Thread %d is unable to allocate memory.", myID);

        }

        int memberCount = 0;

        //Put in bucket
        for (int j = 0; j < randomTime; j++)
        {
            if (numArr[j] >= beginRange && numArr[j] <= endRange) {
                temp[memberCount] = numArr[j];
                memberCount++;
            }
        }

        groupMemberCount[myID] = memberCount;

        int* myGroup = (int*)omp_alloc(memberCount * sizeof(int), omp_large_cap_mem_alloc);

        if( myGroup == NULL ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Thread %d is unable to allocate memory.", myID);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < memberCount; i++) {
            myGroup[i] = temp[i];
        }

        //Sort
        quickSort(myGroup, 0, memberCount - 1);
        printf("\nThread %d of %d has finished sorting.", myID, totalThread);

        //Find the start of output array
        int startIndex = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < myID; i++ ){
            startIndex += groupMemberCount[i];
        }

        //Combine array
        for (int k = 0; k < memberCount; k++) {

            outputArr[startIndex + k] = myGroup[k];

        }

        printf("\nArray from thread %d has combined.", myID);

        omp_free(myGroup, omp_large_cap_mem_alloc);
        omp_free(temp, omp_large_cap_mem_alloc);
    }

    free(numArr);
    free(outputArr);
    free(groupMemberCount);

    clock_t end = clock();

    timeSpent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nTime spent sorting: %f seconds.\n", timeSpent);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with `gcc -fopenmp ./bucketSort.c -o ./bucketSort`. Everything runs fine until I start testing with 100K integers (I wrote 200K in the topic because my program allocate it twice). The program immediately return `malloc(): corrupted top size` after printing `Finished Random` (so the first 100K in `numArr` is fine?). This is the first time I used `malloc()` and `omp_alloc()`, so feel free to correct me if I've done something wrong. I'm running this code in Ubuntu WSL btw.

What I've tried:

- I tried `calloc()` but the result is the same, error after 2nd `calloc()`.
- I tried increase `ulimit` to `unlimit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, valgrind or `-fsanitize=address` give good diagnostics for such errors.

Compiling and linking with `-fsanitize=address` shows that there is a heap overflow on this line:

```
                temp[memberCount] = numArr[j];
```

The `memberCount` variable is equal to `rangePerBucket` at this point.  Both are one less than `randomTime`.  But the `temp` array has only `rangePerBucket` elements, so that index is out of range.

Comment: TBH, `valgrind` with flags `-g -ggd3`, is very powerful

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I completely forget that there might be duplicate number so the number in the bucket might exceed the bucket range! I actually have tried using `valgrind` too, but I cannot make sense of the output so I don't know what to do. Thank you again!